# Getting out of a potential deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I ran into what would SEEM to be a deadlock. Does a deadlock sound a little like:

- Can't close window
- Can't terminate without terminate button on the IDE
- Blank and nothing happens, with no Exceptions or errors at all.

if those are the things that happen in a deadlock, then I probably have half the problem solved already. I have two threads that I know of are running: `AWT-EventQueue-0` and `frameThread`.

This is using a custom library that I built and isn't fully developed yet (what you might call alpha-beta stage?). I decided to use it to make a Pong game. Actually my mentor assigned me the game. I'm just going to use my library with it.

My library uses Swing components and I doubt that has anything to do with it.

I would like to point out that the [intrinsic locks according to the oracle tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) state that

> "When a thread invokes a synchronized method, it automatically acquires the intrinsic lock for that method's object and releases it when the method returns. The lock release occurs even if the return was caused by an uncaught exception."

before doing what this says, I had done a synchronized block to acquire the lock from the only thread I know of in my program that could have the lock. Failed. So I made the method synchronized and, well, the bullet points listed above happened.

my code is

```
// Threads
static ThreadManager tm = new ThreadManager() {

    @Override
    protected void runFrameThread() {//ThreadManager has threads in it that you can start.
        while (true) {               //These are just the abstract inherited methods the
            Main.jpane.repaint();    // threads inside the manager call
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void runMathThread() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void runIntenseMathThread() {
    }

};

// set frame rate
static {
    tm.setFPS(30L);
}
```

```
public synchronized void draw(Graphics g) {// main problem: synchronized method here.
    try {
        wait(hertz);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    g.setColor(rgb);
    g.fillRect(this.x, this.y, width, height);
}
```

if that doesn't help, you can try looking through my code...

[My Code Repository for the Pong game](https://github.com/LinkTheProgrammer/Pong)

My best bet is its something wrong with what Im doing to delay the method. what I want to do is have an update rate for every object at a set rate of 'x' `hertz`. It *would* be easier if it was a return type method (not void).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You state:

> My library uses Swing components and I doubt that has anything to do with it

I fear that you may be very wrong. You appear to be completely blocking the Swing event dispatch thread (the EDT) with your while loop, and since this thread is responsible for all Swing graphics and user interaction, this will effectively freeze your GUI.

- Rather than a `while (true)` loop that will block the EDT, use a Swing Timer instead.
- Don't pause your graphics drawing as this will make your program seem poorly responsive.
- Don't call synchronize from within a painting method.
- Don't change the state of your objects from within a painting method such as `paintComponent` (i.e., don't call your `updateGame()` method from within paintComponent). This is because you never have full control over whether or even if this method will be called. It can be called out of your control by the JVM in response to a request by the OS to clean a dirty region, and the JVM may ignore your request for a repaint if repaint requests are stacking up.

Comment: Thank you for a very straightforward explanation on what to do. I had no idea. Also at the time I thought Swing had nothing to do with it but then I remembered Swing doesn't like concurrency as per the Oracle java docs.

Answer (score 2):

This does appear to be a deadlock, and it most certainly has something to do with the use of Swing. The symptom of the whole application hanging is usually caused by the event dispatch thread (EDT) being deadlocked.

The problem appears to be in this code, which is in your `Ball.java` class:

```
public synchronized void draw(Graphics g) {
    try {
        wait(hertz);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    ...
}
```

It appears that the `hertz` field is not explicitly initialized, and thus it has its default value of `0L`. A value of zero for the `wait(timeout)` method will block indefinitely, that is, it will wait with no timeout. It doesn't appear that this object is ever notified, so this method will hang the calling thread forever. This method is called from the `JPanel.paintComponent` method, which is called by the EDT, so this freezes the application's user interface.

Don't try to control the update rate by sleeping or pausing within the painting routines. The painting routines should always do as little work as possible, inspecting the current state of your model and issuing the appropriate graphics calls, and returning as quickly as possible.

Your program is multi-threaded, so you will need to synchronize your objects. The thread manager threads are updating the game objects and the EDT is painting using the game objects.
Access to your objects will occur on multiple threads, thus the need for synchronization. The synchronized blocks (or methods) should do as little as possible: get in, update (or paint), and get out. Code on the EDT should never call `wait` as that will probably cause poor repaint performance and responsiveness. The update threads should do as much computation as possible outside of the lock, and simply update the game objects with new values while the lock is held. This will minimize the amount of time the EDT is blocked acquiring the lock during the repaint cycle.

Comment: You're contribution is helpful in explaining more in-depth than a quick rundown. Also, Im quite new and this is my first game. Only 2 years of experience so I could use all the help I could get. Thank you!

Comment: oh and hertz is initialized in the creation of the Paddle object and Ball object. (They do about the same thing). I probably shouldnt ask this except in a new question, but how should I go about giving different update rates to certain objects?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726578/how-to-use-swing-timers-to-make-an-overall-update-rate