# How to use Swing Timers to make an overall update rate?

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, swing, timer

In other words I want to be able to run my program at a certain level of hertz. This is a partial extension of my other question [Getting out of a potential deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719350/getting-out-of-a-potential-deadlock).

First of all, I read up a bit on the Java docs by oracle on [how to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), however is there a simpler way so I can just, instead of calling `wait()` to pause the current thread for a certain time and screw up my Swing-based Pong game, to do this?

@Hover_Craft_Full_Of_Eels states

> "Rather than a while (true) loop that will block the EDT, use a Swing Timer instead."

However, I have never worked with Swing Timers, neither have I heard of them nor my mentor who taught me. Can I please have an example of how I should use and implement these Swing Timers?

#### EDIT:

I find the explanation of how to use Swing Timers rather confusing. That is why I could use some help from stackoverflow please.

As a side note:

Is there a way to make the images move smoothly by just having the image move one pixel at a time and then use the Swing Timer(s) to make the speed, or rate at which the image moves one pixel,  faster or slower this way? This is largely the effect I want to create. Otherwise if the image is skipping pixels, even at a high frame rate, your gonna see the image jumping like 5 pixels each time it moves.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I please have an example of how I should use and implement these Swing Timers?

Read more about [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Here is the sample code:

```
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      //...Perform a task...
  }
};
new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Find a [Sample code here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html)

[image]

---

> Is there a way to make the images move smoothly by just having the image move one pixel at a time?

Sample code: (*Move an image 1px horizontally left to right at interval of 200 ms*)

```
private int x = 1;
...
final Image image = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/1.png"));
final JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image,x,10,null);
    }
};

int delay = 200; // milliseconds
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        x++;
        if (x > 100) {
            x = 1;
        }
        panel.repaint();
    }
};
new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```